# How to convert a series of C++ source codes to Matlab mex

Tags: c++, matlab

I downloaded an open source toolkit on this website: http://openframeworks.cc/. Now I would like to integrate this toolkit into MATLAB so that I can do signal processing with MATLAB and this toolkit gives certain CG rendering animation based on MATLAB processing results.

I have read MATLAB instruction of how to make a mex file and I figured out how to do that in the case of dealing with only one .cpp file. BUT in my case, I have a bunch of C++ codes like more than 1000 files including .cpp and .h files. Since these codes need to be compiled and built in order to run, I don't know how can I use the functions in them. How can I make a mex files for the whole code?

Comment: You have a few options... unity build, pass multiple files to MEX, set up a makefile/project outside MATLAB that links with the MATLAB import libraries.  What is your environment (OS, MATLAB version and bitness, compiler and version)?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot posting my environment. Windows 8.1, MATLAB R2014a 64-bit, Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++). I do not know which option is straightforward but I prefer passing these files to a mex.